# Problems upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04 at xorg

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

Process seemed to be working until stalled in the install phase, before cleanup.

Computer will restart in 16.04

I tried redoing using software updater, but the choice to upgrade will not reappear.  It does find LOTS of files to update, tried that, seemed to complete, but still no 18.04.

I'm trying to complete manually, but no luck so far.

Comment: Which method did you use to upgrade your system from 16.04 to 18.04?

Comment: I tried first by responding to the software update window to upgrade to 18.04.

The reference above is about trying to restart the upgrade by starting the software updater again after the failed attempt, when the option to upgrade had disappeared.  It found MANY things to update, but it failed to complete.

Comment: I would switch to terminal to try to fix: First I would `sudo apt update` and watch the output.  If it has reverted the change, you'll note `xenial` in your messages being the code name for 16.04, if however you see 'bionic' (code name for 18.04) sources have already been changed. If it shows 'xenial' I'd run `do-release-upgrade` which is the command to release-upgrade from terminal. If however it showed 'bionic' it means it's already performed a good portion of the upgrade, and I'd likely `sudo apt full-upgrade` to try and have it complete. Post any messages in your question if you need help.

Comment: I continued to work on it, and eventually killed it.  I restored from a clone copy.

I really need to know every detail on how to prepare the computer for the cleanest, most problem free, update. I need to make sure I forget nothing - For example: 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
or instead sudo apt-get clean

ANYTHING else I can to to clean, prepare, check / fix errors, etc. before I try again...

I'm not sure if your previous suggestions would be good for starting a fresh try at upgrade.

Also how to update (NOT reinstall) from disk?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest a new question for what you're asking now.  Your alternative is to modify your question as it stands, but I'd start fresh.  For best results, you want to remove non-Ubuntu-repository software (ie. anything else added, any PPA's or 3rd party sources), ensure you're fully update/dist-upgraded. I usually then re-boot & `do-release-upgrade` from term (after checking I'm not going to run out of disk space). Also provide details (is it a server, desktop etc)

Comment: Another alternative is download the 18.04 ISO & write to media; validate it then use with something-else (ensure you have no format selected), pick your partitions, it'll take note of your added programs, erase system directories (as long as you selected no-format) then install, re-add back your additional software (if Ubuntu repos), then ask to reboot. It won't touch your user directories (unless you had format ticked) and is far faster.  It's my last-resort fix; and this does assume desktop.

Comment: The problem machine is a desktop.  I also have an almost identical machine that did upgrade almost properly except for a font problem I then fixed.

I'm adding a different question per your suggestion.